# Wpf gridcontrol devexpress. Конвертер при привязке

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

```
<dxg:GridColumn ReadOnly="True" FieldName="Duration" Header="Время выполнения (с.)" Width="*"/>
```

В данное поле привязывается значение типа int, представляет собой количество секунд. Как мне выводить значение, во время привязки, в формате {0} ч. {1} мин.?

Comment: Использовать `StringFormat`?

Comment: Пожалуйста, можете привести пример?

Comment: DevExpress? Да не за что в жизни, вы меня конечно простите, но эту помойку ради тестов устанавливать вообще не хочу. Если брать [документацию](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/6094/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Grid-View-Data-Layout/Columns-and-Card-Fields/Creating-Columns-and-Binding-Them-to-Data-Properties), то вам достаточно убрать `FieldName` и переделать его на `Binding = "{Binding Duration, StringFormat=XXX}"`, где `XXX` - нужный вам вид (пример: `{}{0:hh}:{0:mm}`).